# Any 'uboot-mkimage' available for Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: u-boot, ubuntu-14.04

When cross-compiling a Linux kernel the final stage of the build fails because mkimage is not installed.

Which package do I need to install to my new 'Ubuntu Trusty' installation to get the mkimage utility.

I couldn't find any references.
Any suggestions?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic, better suited for http://askubuntu.com/

Comment: @Yuval if you build u-boot from source you will get an "tools/mkimage". It is built from scratch.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The package you are looking for is named [`u-boot-tools`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/u-boot-tools).